# SQL updating a row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have tried to make it so that when the `addLate` function is called, the `lates` column in the `student` table increments by one. However, the `lates` column in the `student` table does not seem to update.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Details</h2></legend>
        <label>First Name: </label><input type = "text" id="firstname" style = "background-color: lightgrey" readonly><br><br>
        <label>First Name: </label><input type = "text" id="lastname" style = "background-color: lightgrey" readonly><br><br>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Information</h2></legend>
        <label> Current date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="datelate" style = "background-color: lightgrey" readonly><br><br>
        <label> Detention date:</label>
        <input id = "detentiondate" type="date" ><br><br>
        <label>Time: </label>
            <select id="mora">
                <option value="AM">Morning</option>
                <option value="PM">Afternoon</option>
            </select>
        <br> <br>
        <label> Reason:</label>
        <textarea id = "reason" rows="2" cols="60"></textarea><br><br>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <button type="button"  onclick="relocate();">Cancel</button>

    <button type="button" id="addlate" onclick="addLate();">Add late</button>
```

Script:

```
if (window.openDatabase) {
    var mydb = openDatabase("students2_db", "0.1", "A Database of Students", 1024 * 1024);

    mydb.transaction(function (t) {
         t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, mclass TEXT, aclass TEXT, com TEXT, lates INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");
         t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lates (lid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, flname TEXT, llname TEXT, time TEXT, reason TEXT, date TEXT, nextdet TEXT)");
    });

} else {
    alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}

function relocate() {
window.location.href = "AddLatecoming.html";
}

function getname() {
    mydb.transaction(function (t) {
         t.executeSql("SELECT fname FROM student WHERE id = ?", [localStorage.id], updateList);
    });
}

function getname2() {
    mydb.transaction(function (t) {
         t.executeSql("SELECT lname, lname FROM student WHERE id = ?", [localStorage.id], updateList2);
    });
}

function updateList(transaction, results) {

    var listitems = "";

    var listholder = document.getElementById("firstname");

    listholder.innerHTML = "";

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

        var row = results.rows.item(i);

    document.getElementById("firstname").value = " " + row.fname;}

    document.getElementById("firstname").style.fontWeight = "900";


}

function updateList2(transaction, results) {

    var listitems = "";

    var listholder = document.getElementById("lastname");

    listholder.innerHTML = "";

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

        var row = results.rows.item(i);

document.getElementById("lastname").value = " " + row.lname;}

document.getElementById("lastname").style.fontWeight = "900";

localStorage.id= undefined;

}

function ClearFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mora").value = "";
}


function addLate() {

    if (mydb) {

        var flname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var llname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var date = document.getElementById("datelate").value;
        var nextdet = document.getElementById("detentiondate").value;
        var time = document.getElementById("mora").value;
        var reason = document.getElementById("reason").value;

        if (flname !== "" && date !== "" && nextdet !== "" && llname !== "" && reason !== "" && time !== "") {

            mydb.transaction(function (t) {
                t.executeSql("INSERT INTO lates (flname,llname,time,reason,date,nextdet) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" , [flname,llname,time,reason,date,nextdet]);
                t.executeSql("UPDATE student SET lates = lates + 1 WHERE lname =? AND fname = ?", [llname, flname]);
                alert("Entry succesfully added");
                window.location.href = "AddLatecoming.html";
            });
        } else {
            alert("You must fill out all the empty information!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
    }
}
```

Comment: getname2() is silly - why poll the same column twice? The lates column in the student table also only seems to be a duplication of data - it's the same as `SELECT count(lid) FROM lates WHERE llname = ? and flname = ?`. You should give us more information on what is working and what not .. do you see that alert at all? What about the new rows in the lates table?

Comment: @flowtron I understand that its duplicate, I will change it as you have pointed out. All the code works, and the new row is added into the `late` table. I just can't get the `UPDATE student SET lates..` to work.

Comment: works for me just fine - are you sure you've updated your student-table-view .. however you're viewing it?!?! All I modified from a copy of your code is to add a function "addUser" to initialize the row and removed the readonly bits to be able to enter stuff.

Comment: You should invest more effort into database design - the 'lates' column data duplication is just one aspect - how about two students called "John Smith" .. are you sending them both to detention just because the evil one needs to go?

Comment: @flowtron very valid points. I will review the design and make the appropriate changes.